# load specific image before anything else

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm a creating a loading screen for website I am making. The website loads many images, scripts, etc. The HTML and CSS part is great, but I need a way to guarantee that the "loading..." image will be loaded before anything else.

I'm using jQuery, and everything is initiated within `$(function () { ... });`. I imagine that the code for this would need to be called before/outside that block, and the code to remove the loading screen will be called at the very end of that block. Currently, the loading image is set as a DIV background, which is the way I prefer it. However, if it's completely necessary, I will settle for an IMG tag.

**Update: (solution)**

I was able to answer my own question by using a combination of Robin and Vlad's responses. Both were very good, and excellent answers, however the problem is that they were aimed to load an image before another image, rather than load an image before anything else. (CSS, JS, etc...)

Here's the dirty version of what I came up with:

```
var files = [new Image(), document.createElement('link'), document.createElement('script')];
files[0].setAttribute('src', 'images/loading.gif');
files[1].setAttribute('rel', 'stylesheet');
files[1].setAttribute('type', 'text/css');
files[1].setAttribute('href', 'test.css');
files[2].setAttribute('type', 'text/javascript');
files[2].setAttribute('src', 'js/jquery-1.5.1.min.js');
window.onload = function (e) {
    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(files[1]);
    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(files[2]);
}
```

Taking a look at the load sequence on the network tab of Chrome's developer console shows that 'loading.gif' is loaded first, then 4 dummy images, then 'test.css', and then 'jquery.1.5.1.min.js'. The CSS and JS files don't begin to load, until they've been inserted into the head tag. This is exactly what I want.

I'm predicting that I may begin to have some problems, however, when I begin to load a list of files. Chrome reports that sometimes the JS file is loaded first, but the majority of the time the CSS file is loaded first. This isn't a problem, except when I begin to add files to load, I will need to ensure that jQuery is loaded before a script file that uses jQuery.

If anyone has a solution for this, or a way to detect when the CSS/JS files are finished loading, using this method, then please comment. Though, I'm not sure that it's going to be a problem yet. I may need to ask a new question in the future about this, if I start to run into problems.

Thank you to every who has helped with this issue.

**Update: (glitch fix)**

I ended up running into a lot of problem with this method, because the script files were being loaded asynchronously. If I would clear the browser cache, and then load the page, it would finish loading my jquery dependent files first. Then if I refreshed the page, it would work, because jquery was loaded from cache. I solved this by setting up an array of files to load, then putting the load script into a function. Then I would step through each array item using this code:

```
element.onload = function() { 
    ++i; _step();
}
element.onreadystatechange = function() { 
    if (("loaded" === element.readyState || "complete" === element.readyState)) { ++i; _step(); }
}
```

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">$(function() { /* Code thingies here */ })</script> - fires when jquery is loaded. You could load the rest from that function.

Comment: While I was rearranging code, I found that if `$(function() { ... });` is called before the jQuery file is loaded, I get a JS error that `$` is undefined. Though, I'm not even sure I'm going to have a problem with this. I'm not going to worry about it, until I start to run into glitches.

Comment: Just put all your scripts on the lower part of your html body, should solve all these issues.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As long as the "loading..." image is positioned before any other html elements, it should load first. This of course depends on the size of the image. You could put the loading div right after the  tag and position it using 'position:absolute'.
Regarding the code to remove the loading screen, one method is to do the following.

- Put all the images, scripts that need to be loaded in a hidden div (display: none)
- Set up a variable that will hold the total of the images / scripts to be loaded
- Set up a counter variable
- Attach to each image / script the "onload" event
- Everytime the "onload" event is triggered it will call a function that will increment the counter variable and check if the value of the counter equals the value of the total variable
- If all resources have been loaded, fire a custom event that will show the div with the images, and hide the div with the loading screen.

The code below isn't tested so it might not work. Hope it helps

```js
    var totalImages = 0;
    var loadCounter = 0;

    function incrementLoadCounter() {
       loadCounter++;
       if(loadCounter === totalImages) {
          $(document).trigger('everythingLoaded');
       }
    }

    function hideLoadingScreen() {
       $('#loadingScreen').hide();
       $('#divWithImages').show();
    }

    $(document).ready(function(e) {
        $('#loadingScreen').bind('everythingLoaded', function(e) {
            hideLoadingScreen();
        });
        var imagesToLoad = $('img.toLoad');
        totalImages = imagesToLoad.length;

        $.each(imagesToLoad, function(i, item) {
            $(item).load(function(e) {
               incrementLoadCounter();
            })
        });
    })
```

Comment: I may need to resort to a modified version of this. Robin's example works best for loading an image before any other image, however CSS and JS files are still loaded first.

Comment: that's true. If you have a large number of javascript files, you could load the bare minimum of javascript in the head of the document, and put the rest in the footer of the page, right before the body tag closing.

Comment: Can't believe there isn't a good way to do this still. This method is way too clunky and would break my other JS.

Answer (score 21):

You can reuse resource prealoding browser support.

I'm not sure it works across all browsers but in my case this approach helps me to load images first. Also it allows to define concrete images so UI specific could be skipped

First define in header what resource you want to preload and define resource priority

```
<link rel="preload" href="link-to-image" as="image">
```

or

```
<link rel="preload" href="link-to-image">
```

Second line allow to increase loading priority across all object types (scripts / images / styles). First line - only through images.

Then define in body link to image as usual:

```
<img src="link-to-image" alt="">
```

Here is my working example
https://jsfiddle.net/vadimb/05scfL58/

Comment: as of mid 2020, this is still not supported by Firefox (and IE of course). https://caniuse.com/#search=preload

Comment: If you need to preload an image at the same time as the scripts / styles load, then you can up it's priority by changing to as='script' or as='style'. This controls the priority, not the resource type, so it is safe to include images. 'As' priority is in this order: script, style, image

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure if it's possible to enforce.

If it is, try adding this in the head-tag:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    if(document.images)
        (new Image()).src="http://www.image.com/example.png";
</script>
```

In theory that may load and cache that image before anything else.

Comment: @andrewjackson - when you try could you comment if this actually works please.

Comment: I've done some testing, and this works great for ensuring that the image is loaded before any other image, however no matter where I place it or rearrange it, JS and CSS files are always called before the loading image. By now, I'm quite sure it's very possible, because Google.com loads several images before loading any scripts. I may need to resort to loading the image first, and then creating script and link tags within Javscript, instead of using HTML. Or I could try a dirty method by using an iframe.

Comment: Try placing the css and script-tags after the loading-div. This should solve the issue. Consider having a small css-file for the sole purpose of styling your loading-div and add this before the loading-div. Else you could always load all css-tags etc. by adding the html through javascript on the event that the loading picture has been loaded succesfully :)

Comment: I've tried that Robin, but no matter how I rearranged it, Chrome was loading JS and CSS first, no matter what. So I assume it is like this in FF and IE.

Comment: Have you tried adding the html for script and css through jquery: <script type="text/javascript">$(function() { $('document').append('<script type="text/javascript" src="/script.js"></script>'); });</script>

Answer (score 0):

I think if you place the IMG tag at the top of your html body it will be loaded first. If you do not want to move your div just use a copy of the image tag. Once the images is loaded it will be shown in every image tag which shows the same picture.

Comment: Better yet, I may use Robin's code before any CSS/JS files are loaded. It's good in theory. Though, I'm predicting that there's gonna be that one super popular browser, that doesn't want to behave like the rest. I'm going to mark an answer as soon as I get enough testing in, which shouldn't take long.

Answer (score 0):

Or you could use spin.js as loading image. It display this "loading cycle image" via javascript.

Check it out under:
http://fgnass.github.com/spin.js/

Comment: we're talking about a < 3kb gif vs a > 3kb library