# Javascript - loading images

Tags: javascript, html, image

I have a javascript which uses many images, and I want to load them all before the user starts clicking around. The images are a little bit big, so it takes a while. Here's my code:

```
startTest();

function preloadImages() {
    console.log("preload images");
    for(var i = 1; i <= 132; i++) {
        var img = new Image();
        images[i-1] = "images/"+i+".png";
        img.src = images[i-1];
        if(i == 132) {
            img.load = doneLoading();
        }
    }
}

function doneLoading() {
    console.log("done loading");
    document.getElementById("laading").style.display = "none";
    console.log("loading gone");
    showReady();
}

function startTest() {
    console.log("start test");
    trialCount = 0;
    document.getElementById("laading").style.display = "block";

    preloadImages();
    var hammertime = Hammer(document.body).on("touch", function(event) {
        registerTouch(event);
    });

    startTestTime = +new Date();
    console.log("end start test");
}
```

As you can see, `startTest()` is first called, which calls preload images. Here's the issue:
When I load the page in the browser, the javascript console indicates that `"done loading"` has been printed, however the spinny wheel on the tab in the browser shows that the webpage is still loading...

What's going on here? How can I figure out once all my images are done loading?

Comment: possible duplicate of [load specific image before anything else](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7511352/load-specific-image-before-anything-else)

Comment: One thing: you should not assume that the last image you create is the last one to complete (`img.load = doneLoading();` should probably be done for all images and then check that it gets called 132 times)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to check on each image load that the image is the last one to load. Check using a count variable (`loaded`).

```
function preloadImages() {

  var loaded = 0;

  for(var i = 0; i <= 132; i++) {

    var img = new Image();

    images.push("images/"+(i+1)+".png");
    img.src = images[i];

    img.onload = function(){

      loaded++;

      if(!(loaded < 132)){

        // all images have loaded
        doneLoading();

      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you try this code? I put a console.log(loaded) right under loaded++ and it never gets printed... hm. any ideas?

Comment: any difference between "push" and what I did?

Comment: Nah, it's more of a personal preference. When I'm dealing with arrays I like to use the inherent methods provided by the language, as  it ensures the index is correct. Because everything in JavaScript is an Object, it means you can index Arrays just like you can index Objects. I could use negative indices `images[-100] = "foo.jpg";` or even strings `images['bar'] = "bar";`. The inherent Array methods, however, pull rank on this flexibility, making it easier for you to be absolutely sure that you're using an Array the way it should be used: with whole integers as indexes. It's debug friendly.

Answer (score 0):

In order to do a pre-loading, you will have to keep checking the `complete` status for each image that is being downloaded. Since, you can't know beforehand how much time it will take for each image to download (depending on latency or size), you will have to implement a timer which will keep polling the `complete` status on each image.

Here is one possible algorithm:

```
var timer = null, 
    numImages = 132, 
    allImages = new Array; 

function preLoadImages() { 
    document.getElementById('loadcaption').innerHTML = 'Loading images... '; 
    for (var i = 0; i < numImages; i++) { 
        var tmp = "images/" + i + ".png";
        allImages[i] = new Image(); 
        allImages[i].onLoad = imgOnLoad(tmp); 
        allImages[i].src = tmp; 
    }  
    timer = window.setInterval('checkLoadComplete()', 250); 
}  

function imgOnLoad(imgName) { window.status = 'Loading image... ' + imgName; } 

function checkLoadComplete() { 
    for (var i = 0; i < allImages.length; i++) { 
        if (!allImages[i].complete) { 
            imgOnLoad(allImages[i].src); 
            document.getElementById('loadcaption').innerHTML = 'Loading images... ' + Math.round((i/allImages.length)*100,0) + ' %'; 
            return; 
        } 
    } 
    window.clearInterval(timer); 
    document.getElementById('loadcaption').innerHTML = 'Completed.'; 
    window.status = ''; 
}
```

Where `loadcaption` is a simple HTML element to show progress. (You can also use an animated gif for loading animation).

The idea is to keep checking the `complete` status on each image by calling `checkLoadComplete` by a timer. Once all images are (load) `complete`, the `for` loop exits and the timer is cleared.

You start the pre-loading process by calling `preLoadImages();` function.

Comment: Yes @shennan, for most practical purposes this is an overkill. Actually, this is based on one of my previous experiences where cached images were giving a problem. Besides, in case of a large number of images, the `complete` property was not being updated in time. Hence effectively my page was showing pre-load as "finished" a few seconds prematurely. So I had to wait for explicitly checking the `complete` property. Otherwise, your answer is perfect fit. +1 for your answer of course.

Comment: Fair enough. I've never had an issue with cached images, though perhaps I've not come across your user-case before.