# Load sprite image before anything else

Tags: javascript, css, image, sprite, loading

I'm working on a project where I use a sprite image that contains almost all icons including header icons and panels' icons as shown below:

[image]

Sprite Image is something like this (snapshot taken from image editor):

[image]

Now the problem here is when I go from page to page sometimes their places still blank for a while until the sprite is fully loaded. I used image preloading and caching but the problem didn't solved.
I'm looking for a way where I force the browser to load the sprite first before any style or script and then load the page in order to display the icons from the first glance.
Please tell me If I could do that or any advice to solce this issue, because almost all icons in the project are fetched from this sprite, and I spent a lot of times calculating image positioning and I based all my buttons behaviors on the sprite icons positions.
Thanks

Comment: Here's a very similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7511352/load-specific-image-before-anything-else (not marking this as dupe yet though) Also, I'm curious why the browser won't cache the image. Do all pages use the same image URL? What do you see in the network tab? It should show response code 304 for the image.

Comment: Yeah I already saw this post but nothing work for me. Yeah all pages, the header and left panel are included in every single image, and regarding network page I see js and css files loaded before the image, and I think that this is because the size of image that contains a lot of sub icons, my goal here is to force the browser not to load anything until this image is loaded